# Load Balance Web Applications on Windows Docker

Tags: windows, iis, docker, containers, rancher

Is there any information on how to setup load balancers on Windows Docker containers, that also can manage when they scale?

I`m currently using [Rancher](http://rancher.com/) for both Linux and Windows containers, and the built-in load balancer for Docker Linux is very easy to use.

Something like ehazlett/interlock for the Windows Docker Environment would be great.

The Windows container i currently use is [MICROSOFT/IIS](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/)

Hope anyone can shed some light on this issue, thanks :)

Comment: Daniel, did you ever get anywhere on this? I'm waiting patiently for Rancher to release some kind of load balancer for Windows containers, but there doesn't seem to be much movement.

Comment: Hi @Trondh, no I did not get the correct solution.  As cebaztian pointed out, you could use .NET core. But I think I will wait until Rancher get better Windows Support.

Comment: Yup, they finally released some info in the forums about postponing Windows support. So don't hold your breath! I think kubernetes is the best option for Windows containers support right now, a lot of stuff seems to be happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario, everything was wonderful with rancher and linux containers but, when I needed to use windows containers everything changed, I discovered that rancher nor kubernetes offer support for windows containers yet.

Basically you have 3 options:

- You can migrate your traditional .Net application to .Net core and continue using Linux and Rancher containers.
- You can continue using the image *microsoft/iis* and windows containers, but you will need to create a container on different windows server 2016 and use the clusters of NLB in Windows Server 2016.
- List itemYou also have the possibility to deploy your website in different IIS on port 80, and use the clusters of NLB in Windows Server 2016.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Docker networking on Windows containers, this doc is a good place to start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-networking

Also, as of Dec. 2017, Windows engine does not have IP layer routing mesh unlike Linux engine.  That makes it quite bit challenging to load balance unfortunately.  MS team is working on it though.

Another option is to use Docker EE Standard/Advanced, and use UCP which offers HRM (http layer routing mesh).  UCP offers lots of other benefit like LDAP sync too.  Hope this helps.